# Class 'appProdProjectContainer' not found

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony 2.8 and which cleaning production cache I am facing some issue with bootstrap.php.cache

php app/console c:c
Works for me and project running well

php app/console c:c --env=prod

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'appProdProjectContainer' not found in /var/www/html/lsc/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2787
Stack trace:

## 0 /var/www/html/lsc/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2561): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer()

## 1 /var/www/html/lsc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(62): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()

## 2 /var/www/html/lsc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(117): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

## 3 /var/www/html/lsc/app/console(27): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput))

## 4 {main}

thrown in /var/www/html/lsc/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2787

Please help me to figure this.

Comment: removing manually cache/prod folder and re-run `php app/console c:c --env=prod`?

Comment: missing classes with classnames sounding very familiar (something that resembles actual classes, but without all the namespaces and stuff) are in all cases wrapper classes (for lazy loading) that might not have been found, which might be the case, when the cache hasn't been warmed up.

Comment: @AndreaManzi thanks It works. But I can't understand Why it is happening.

Some where I found php 7.2 no more required bootstrap.php.cache to be loaded in app.php. When I remove this from my app.php class Project starts throwing auto load error.  In my symfony 3.4 project I found replaced bootrap.app.cache with require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: have you update composer packages recently?

Comment: yes may be. Actually I found this error when I ```git rm -r --cached```  in my server

Comment: I git rm -r --cached for what dir/file?

Comment: my .gitignore was not working so I did this in project folder.

Comment: if you had already committed the files and are in the .gitignore they are not ignored

Comment: if you want to remove files from git history try https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#using-filter-branch

Answer (score 1):

Try removing cache/prod folder and run

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```